# ACF: If field contain a specific value, update value in another field programatically

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

how can I change the value of a field based on the value of another field programatically?

This other field has already a value but I need to replace / update it.

To be more precise:

If the Text Field named `type` has value **Houses** AND another Text Field named `service` has value **2**, this should be updated in **NOT AVAILABLE**.

Or ...

If the Text Field named `type` has value **Parks** AND another Text Field named `service` has value **2**, this should be updated in **AVAILABLE**.

Or ...

If the Text Field named `type` has value **Store** AND another Text Field named `service` has value **2**, this should be updated in **COMING SOON**.

I read the update_field doc but I could not solve this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to WPSE @Richdn. Please make sure you read [these guidelines](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on questions and update your question as necessary. I'm not sure this is within the scope of WPSE either and may be better suited to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Did you trying something like this in a JS script?

Assuming you wants to edit the `service` text field.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(() => {
  const textfield_type = document.querySelector('input[name="type"]');
  const textfield_service = document.querySelector('input[name="service"]');

  const updateField = () => {
    if (textfield_type.getAttribute('value') === 'Houses' && textfield_service.getAttribute('value') === '2') {
      textfield_service.setAttribute('value', 'NOT AVAILABLE');
    }

    // ... other rules
  }

  // Launch the event only if the two fields exists
  if (textfield_type !== null && textfield_service !== null) {
    textfield_service.addEventListener('focusout', () => updateField());
  }
});
```